# Unable to set shares and flairs targets

Tags: support, area-51, flair, share-this

I have used the **Area51 Proposal** shares and also the **flairs** of profile but they don't target new tab or window
I tried to add the `target="_blank"` but that doesn't seems to be work

### With Target

[image]

[image]

### WithOut Target

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's definitely not the duplicate of What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?, but yes the answer given there might solve the issue

Comment: Here on Meta "the answer given there might solve the issue" is enough to be a reason to mark as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, this is very much [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign); the limited subset of HTML that the Stack Exchange Markdown flavor supports doesn't support specifying a target. This applies to **all** links, not just Area51 promotions.

See [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites), only `href` and `title` attributes are permitted.